# App for recording Kodi videos

Tags: google-play-store, kodi

I sometimes stream video using the Kodi app for my android Note 4.  I will be traveling on a plane and would like to know if there is a way to capture and record a few movies and view them later.  Does anyone know of such an App?

Comment: How about using a plugin to download the videos to sd_card then view them later?

Comment: Can you recommend one?